# How to compare files in different folder with windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to compare files that have same names but in different folder. I call an my diffTool.exe from bat.file and give file names to this exe as a paramater.

My script is like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal 

set MYDIR="D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release"
set firstFolder=%MYDIR%\folder1
set secondFolder=%MYDIR%\folder2

for /r "%firstFolder%" %%F in (.) do (
    echo %%F
    for /r "%secondFolder%" %%G in (%%F) do (   
       call D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\diffTool.exe %%F %%G
    )
 )
```

How can I take just file names from string? How can I pass this filename to second loop and call an exe with these file names?

Output is like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call for /? and have a look at the syntax,

Comment: What do you mean? I am not so proficient in batch scripting.

Comment: Open a command prompt and run "for /?". You will see that for supports things like "%~ni"

Comment: I tried but I can not see about %~ni

Comment: `for /?`, third page: `%~nI        - erstellt nur den Dateinamen von %I` (my Windows is German, yours will display your language. Check your glasses, if you have some ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you are right =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal 

set "MYDIR=D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release"
set "firstFolder=%MYDIR%\folder1"
set "secondFolder=%MYDIR%\folder2"

for /r "%firstFolder%" %%F in (*) do (
    for /r "%secondFolder%" %%G in (*) do (   
       call D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\diffTool.exe "%%F" "%%G"
    )
 )
pause
```

**EDIT**

To only compare files with the same name+extension, use this:

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal 

set "MYDIR=D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release"
set "firstFolder=%MYDIR%\folder1"
set "secondFolder=%MYDIR%\folder2"

for /r "%firstFolder%" %%F in (*) do (
    for /r "%secondFolder%" %%G in (*) do (   
       if "%%~nxF"=="%%~nxG" call D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\diffTool.exe "%%F" "%%G"
    )
 )
pause
```

Comment: Yeah, That worked. But Output is like this:
Files D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder1\myFile1.txt and D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder2\myFile2.txt differ
Files D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder1\myFile2.txt and D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder2\myFile1.txt differ
Files D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder1\myFile2.txt and D:\Workspace\diffTool\Release\folder2\myFile2.txt differ
I want to see different file with same name.

Comment: @Wilmort so you only want to compare files with different names?

Comment: No, just I want to compare files with same names but in different folder. So If their insides are different so my script detects them.

Comment: @Wilmort sorry, I meant with the same name. The second part of my answer should solve that now.